# Is there a way to check element in C# Linq to see what the value is?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

My program could be given two different kinds of xml files. The only way to tell the difference is by seeing what device it came from. How would I get the device name from this xml document?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataFileSetup>
    <System Name="Local">
        <SysInfo>
            <Devices>
                <RealMeasurement>
                    <Hardware></Hardware>
                    <Device Type="MultiDevice">
                        <DriverBuffSizeInSec>5</DriverBuffSizeInSec>
                        <Card Index="0">
                            <DeviceName>SIRIUSi</DeviceName>
                            <DeviceSerialNumber>D017F09216</DeviceSerialNumber>
                            <FirmwareVersion>7.3.45.75</FirmwareVersion>
                            <VCXOValue>8802</VCXOValue>
                        </Card>
                    </Device>
                </RealMeasurement>
              </Devices>
            </SysInfo>
         </System>
   </DataFileSetup>
```

The simple

```
var deviceType = xdoc.Element("DeviceName").Value;
```

either errors because there is nothing there or if i delete `.Value` it is just null.

Is there a simple way to get this value?

Comment: You tried xpath? //DataFileSetup/System/SysInfo/Devices/RealMeasurement/Device/Card/DeviceName

Comment: Do the two xmls have different structure? Will the xpath to DeviceName differ in them? A fool proof solution depends on that.

Comment: You could check `.Descendants("DeviceName").Any();` if it exists and get the value.

Comment: Value will give exception.  Instead cast : var deviceType = (string)xdoc.Element("DeviceName");  in thin case I would use descendents : List<XElement> deviceNames = xdoc.Descendents("DeviceName").ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following.

> c#

```
void Main()
{
    const string fileName = @"e:\temp\device.xml";

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
    Console.WriteLine(xdoc.Descendants("DeviceName").FirstOrDefault()?.Value);
}
```

> Output

```
SIRIUSi
```

Answer (score 0):

I like using a Dictionary in this case :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<string, XElement> dict = doc.Descendants("Device")
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Descendants("DeviceName").FirstOrDefault(), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```